# return all the HtmlPage's HTML

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want the entire HTML for a given HtmlPage object.

What property should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HtmlUnit, an [`HtmlPage`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html) implements the [`Page`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/Page.html) interface; that means that you can use [`Page#getWebResponse()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/Page.html#getWebResponse()) to get the entire web response returned to generate the `HtmlPage`, and from there it's easy ([`WebResponse#getContentAsString()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html#getContentAsString())).  Here's a method that does what you want...

```
public String getRawPageText(WebClient client, String url)
        throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
    return page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
}
```

Or, using an `HtmlPage` object that you've already fetched:

```
public String getRawPageText(HtmlPage page) {
    return page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
}
```

Comment: Since mrblah specifically mentioned an HtmlPage object, I would simply make the page itself an argument, instead of passing in a WebClient and a URL. But the essential idea is absolutely correct.

Comment: Totally -- I just added that.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do this is [`HtmlPage.asXml`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SgmlPage.html#asXml%28%29) -- It may not be perfect, as in, it may not exactly match what you would see if you did "View Source" in a normal browser, but I've found it to be very helpful for developing and debugging HtmlUnit code.

Comment: Yep, this actually reconstructs the document, so you won't get the HTML as it was passed on the wire -- which makes things either nicer (if you want a tidied version of the doc) or harder (if you're looking for the original HTML).