# HTMLUnit HtmlPage.getBody() returns null even though the response contains a <body> tag

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using HTMLUnit in Java to extract information from website. 
Ran into a strange phenom where the page is not fully parsed into the DOM tree. 
After the following:

```
HtmlPage lineHours = (HtmlPage) _webClient.getTopLevelWindows().get(1).getEnclosedPage();
```

Watching the expression lineHours.asXml() results in the following (... marks ommitted sensitive data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script ...>
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

While printing lineHours.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() results in the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script ...>
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
<body>
  <div> ...
```

In short, the body tag is not parsed into the DOM tree. and therefore all XPath queries and helper methods such as HtmlPage.getBody() fail. In a regular browser the page renders well.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Tomer

Comment: Plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010642/return-all-the-htmlpages-html link to understand

Comment: Didn't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved by parsing the DOM tree using a Xerces parser and retrieving the result from it.